# Is it possible to convert this if-else chain to switch-case? - Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity

Here is the code:

```
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(leftMouseButton))
    {
        OnLeftMouseButtonDown();
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButton(leftMouseButton))
    {
        OnLeftMouseButtonHold();
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(leftMouseButton))
    {
        OnLeftMouseButtonUp();
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(rightMouseButton))
    {
        OnRightMouseButtonDown();
    }
    else if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(rightMouseButton))
    {
        OnRightMouseButtonUp();
    }
```

So is it possible to convert this big chain to switch-case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Downvoters, please leave a comment so I can see what's wrong with this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really, no. Given what you are trying to do, your code looks OK to me.

Anything is possible really, but it would be pretty convoluted and ultimately be a silly thing to do. :)

Comment: It is OK indeed; I just wondered if switch-case is possible or not.

Comment: Anything is possible really, but it would be pretty convoluted and ultimately be a silly thing to do. :)

Comment: Although I do agree with you that OP's code looks ok as it currently is, I think you should then edit your answer. I mean, in your answer you "no" to question "is it possible". Then in the comments you suggest that yes, it is possible, just not advisable. Making that to become part of your answer would be great in my opinion